# R t_test errors with 'not enough 'y' observations', but there are plenty of x and y observations

Tags: r, t-test

Here's an small example of my data.

```
data <- structure(list(cag = c(111.766666666667, 112.66, 115.483333333333, 
114.67, 114.723333333333, 107.823333333333, 107.2, 110.493333333333, 
107.713333333333, 132.566666666667, 132.663333333333), timepoint = structure(c(6L, 
6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 11L), levels = c("0", 
"3", "5", "7", "9", "10", "11", "14", "18", "19", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "27", "28", "29", "30", "34", "35", "37", "39", 
"41"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


> print(data)
# A tibble: 11 × 2
     cag timepoint
   <dbl> <fct>    
 1  112. 10       
 2  113. 10       
 3  115. 21       
 4  115. 21       
 5  115. 21       
 6  108. 0        
 7  107. 0        
 8  110. 0        
 9  108. 10       
10  133. 21       
11  133. 21
```

I'd like to run a pairwise t-test of the 'cag' measurement between pairs of timepoints, but it's saying there aren't enough y observations.

```
> data %>%
+   t_test(cag ~ timepoint)
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `t.test.default()`:
! not enough 'y' observations
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I can't work out what's going wrong. There are enough observations in each group (timepoint), and the class of each column seems fine.

```
> class(data$cag)
[1] "numeric"
> class(data$timepoint)
[1] "factor"
```

Any ideas?

### Addition

Someone below suggested it was because there were more than two groups. However, this example here works fine, and there are more than two groups:

```
data2 <- structure(list(cag = c(114.243333333333, 114.473333333333, 115.276666666667, 
114.243333333333, 114.51, 115.3, 115.476666666667, 115.56), timepoint = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("6", "10", "13", "26"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

> print(data2)
# A tibble: 8 × 2
    cag timepoint
  <dbl> <fct>    
1  114. 6        
2  114. 10       
3  115. 13       
4  114. 6        
5  115. 10       
6  115. 13       
7  115. 26       
8  116. 26 

> data %>%
+   t_test(cag ~ timepoint)
# A tibble: 6 × 10
  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic    df     p p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1 cag   6      10         2     2    -13.5   1    0.047 0.094 ns          
2 cag   6      13         2     2    -89.6   1    0.007 0.036 *           
3 cag   6      26         2     2    -30.6   1    0.021 0.062 ns          
4 cag   10     13         2     2    -36.7   1.70 0.002 0.011 *           
5 cag   10     26         2     2    -22.6   1.37 0.01  0.04  *           
6 cag   13     26         2     2     -5.32  1.16 0.094 0.094 ns
```

Ultimately the aim is to plot like so:

```
ttest <- data2 %>%
t_test(cag ~ timepoint) %>%
add_y_position()


ggplot(data, aes(x=timepoint, y=cag)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(width=0.1,height=0) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(ttest, label = ifelse("p.adj.signif" %in% names(ttest), "p.adj.signif", "p"), tip.length = 0.01, hide.ns = T)
```

[image]

Comment: T.test is for 2 categories. You have more than 2 categories. so it wont work

Comment: But it works fine for some other data of mine - I've added a working example above. Ultimately the aim is a plot, as above. I've added above for example

Comment: Each t-test is comparing two groups though isn't it? It's a pairwise comparison of all of the groups in there

Comment: @jpsmith - the function looks like it gives pairwise results when there are more than two groups.  OP should specify which package is being used.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @Mike - Untested but try `data %>% droplevels() %>% t_test(...)`.  There are factor levels with no observations in the data you posted.

Comment: Unfortunately that's still giving the same error about not enough y observations

Comment: It works for me if I use droplevels as Mike suggests

Comment: It does on the simple example above, but not with the slightly larger real data. However, I have found the solution. The problem was the groups with only one observation. If I removed them, then it works fine

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento! Didn’t realize it was pairwise implemented through another package. Glad folks were there to work it out!

Comment: Actually, just tested and now I'm getting 'not enough 'x' observations'. Argh. I'll update the example above

Comment: OK, so now I've got it all working. It was indeed the groups with only one observation that was the problem. Now all working. Thanks all!